# How dealing with categorical variables in Calibrated Classifier?

Tags: categorical-data, calibration, catboost

I am dealing with calibration curve for catboost model.

cat=CatBoostClassifier()

calib=CalibratedClassifierCV(base_estimator=cat, method='sigmoid', cv=2)

calib.fit(XX,yy,cat_features=??)

How can I deal with categorical variables in the fit of calibrated classifier?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the categorical indices during the model constructor.
in your case:

```
cat=CatBoostClassifier(cat_features=categorical_positions)
```

and then continue as you wrote.

categorical_positions is a list if categorical features indices.

Comment: Even if I pass it, I got an error when calling fit function.
The error that appears is the following:

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'USA'

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that sklearn CalibratedClassifierCV doesn't support string values.
To overcome this problem you need to change string values of categorical features to integer values (for example enumerate them). CatBoost will still treat them as categorical, because you have mentioned it in cat_features parameter of CatBoostClassifier, so metrics will be the same.